# Database scalar function mapping - invocation causes System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

I have an database application and want to use a scalar user defined function in my application. The return value is integer. On invocation

```
int pqs_id = Entities.UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID(param_SHH_RecordingOrder, param_TillDT_UTC, param_TillDT_UTC);
```

I get the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
> at GB.PPC.EntityDataModel.Entities.UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID(Nullable`1 shh_RecordingOrder, Nullable`1 fromDateTime_UTC, Nullable`1 tillDateTime_UTC) in D:\Projects\Reporting\Source-DBAccess\PPC.EntityDataModel\Entities_Functions.cs:line 50
> at DBAccess.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Reporting\Source-DBAccess\PostgreSQL.AccessTest\Program.cs:line 299

I set a breakpoint in OnModelCreating(), but the app didn't pass it.

This is how my database context **Entities** is configured:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        if (_useLoggerFactory)
        {
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
        }

        if (DatabaseProvider == DatabaseProvider.System_Data_SqlClient)
        { 
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectString);
        }
        if (DatabaseProvider == DatabaseProvider.Npgsql)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectString);
            optionsBuilder.UseLowerCaseNamingConvention();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //..
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(Entities)
                    .GetMethod(nameof(UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID), new[] { typeof(int?), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTime?) }))
                    .HasSchema("ppc")
                    .HasName("UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID");
    }

    [DbFunction]
    public static int UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID(int? shh_RecordingOrder, DateTime? fromDateTime_UTC, DateTime? tillDateTime_UTC) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

On solving this problem I read e.g. [New features in EF Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0/#database-scalar-function-mapping) and [Mapping your own scalar functions](https://www.allhandsontech.com/data-professional/entityframework/entity-framework-core-advanced-mapping/), but non could not solve my problem.

I use:

- TargetFramework: netcoreapp3.1
- Npgsql: Version="4.1.11"
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL: Version="3.1.18"

Any help to solve my problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: These methods can only be "called" inside EF queries, where they are translated to SQL and never really executed. Otherwise you simply call your `=> throw new NotSupportedException();`

Comment: @ivan-stoev: Thank you for the clarification, but how can I then use scalar user defined function in my application?

Comment: Well, if you need to call it from the application, then you probably should not map it as database scalar function. Just a regular db context instance method which calls `Database.ExecuteSqlRaw` or `ExecuteSqlInterpolated`.

Comment: @ivan-stoev: At the end, my solution is a linq-query on a DBSet<> instance using the scalar user defined function - it works fine. Refer to my answer post for details. Again, thanks fpr you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
var statisticID = db.TPQS_ProductionQuantityStatistic
                            .Select(pqs => new
                                    {
                                        newPQS_ID = Entities.UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID(paramIntValue, paramDateTimeValueFrom, paramDateTimeValueTill)
                                    }
                                   )
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Since the scalar function always returns a value, it is available in statisticID.newPQS_ID.

Some further explainations. The proposal of @Ivan-Stoev to use `DataBase.ExecuteSqlRaw` is not applicable, because
[ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1) returns the number of affected rows, what I can't need. The UDF **UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID** returns a value which is realted to the passed parameters.

The above shown solution worked fine - in any ways. Then I truncated the entity **TPQS_ProductionQuantityStatistic** because I wanted to run my testcases against the database from the very first beginning. I got a *null reference exception* on `statisticID`. Apperently the UDF is not executed when the entity references an empty database table. So my final solution was to execute the UDF against a entity which related database table is for sure never empty - **TSYP_SystemParam**.

**Final solution**

```
var statisticID = db.TSYP_SystemParam
                            .Select(pqs => new
                                    {
                                        newPQS_ID = Entities.UFN_QueryForNewPQS_ID(paramIntValue, paramDateTimeValueFrom, paramDateTimeValueTill)
                                    }
                                   )
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know if there is another way to achive my task, but this way works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).